# Filter sharepoint list using multi line text field

Tags: list, javascript, filter, ajax

I'm trying to filter a sharepoint list using ajax api.

So one of the filtered field is `Multi line text field` (FieldType.Note) , after performing request it throws an error telleing that the field can not be used in filter expression !

```
"{"error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException","message":{"lang":"fr-FR","value":"Le champ \u00ab\u00a0Description\u00a0\u00bb de type \u00ab\u00a0Note\u00a0\u00bb ne peut pas \u00eatre utilis\u00e9 dans l\u2019expression de filtre des requ\u00eates."}}}"
```

Here is an example of my req :

```
"http://siteurl/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Test')/items?
 $filter=(substringof('searchText',Description))"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is by design.

Multi line text cannot be used as filter expressions.